# does jquery.each check for hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hasownproperty

I've browsed the jquery source, but I am still unsure. Does jQuery.each check for hasOwnProperty or does it not?

if I loop over an object with for..in, I need to check. I allways thought I don't need to check when using jquery..

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-each-and-hasownproperty-check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, jQuery.each does not check hasOwnProperty as you can see at this issue: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5499